# Python version of Java's 'class extends'?

Tags: python, class

I am making a class in Python, as shown:

```
class BaseClass:
  def __init__(self, number):
    self.number = number
    self.id = "Class Base"

  def behavior(self, person):
    print("Hello,", person)
```

Now I want to use this class as a base. I am creating a new class called `SubClass` which has its `self.id` set to `Subclass`, and a new function called `add`.
I could simply type this:

```
class SubClass:
  def __init__(self, number):
    self.number = number
    self.id = "Subclass"

  def behavior(self, person):
    print("Hello,", person)

  def add(self, one, two):
    return one + two
```

But I was wondering if I could do this like you can in Java, where you could type `class SubClass extends BaseClass`.
Is this possible in Python? I am specifically looking for Python 3.x, but any version should work.

Comment: `class SubClass(BaseClass):`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

class inheritance is done in python this way:

```
class SubClass(BaseClass):
    ...
```

Comment: It is probably a good idea to extend the `object` class as well.

Comment: @MalikBrahimi All classes implicitly inherit from `object` in Python 3.